# How to create string concatenation operator which preserves trailing spaces in char(n)

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-concatenation

How to create string concatenation operator which preserves trailing spaces on CHAR(n) type columns in Postgres ?
I tried code below but

```
create temp table test (col1  char(2)) on commit drop;
insert into test values ('A');
select col1 + 'B'
   from test;
```

returns `AB` (without spaces).
How to force it to return `A B` (keep space after A, since A type is char(2) ) so that expression `col1 + 'B'` remains unchaged ?
How to preserve left argument trailing spaces if left argument type is `CHAR(n)` ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.stringconcat(left text, right text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
AS $BODY$
SELECT $1::text || $2::text ;
$BODY$;

CREATE OPERATOR public.+ (
    leftarg = text,
    rightarg = text,
    procedure = public.stringconcat
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
SELECT concat('A'::char(2), 'B');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, testcase in question was not clear. I updated question and added clear testcase. How to force `col1 + 'B'` to return ´A B´ so that expression `col1 + 'B'`  remain unchanged ? I'm creating converter from FoxPro SQL and foxpro uses + operator which returns `A B`. Replacing + operator automatically with concat call with casti looks not possible.